# How can I debug my android app on NexusOne

Tags: android

I have rooted my NexusOne. I can get 'adb shell and su'.

But when I deploy and run my android app on NexusOne and start my application. Under DDMS (connected to the phone of course), I DO NOT see my application. I see some apps but not mine.

How can I make my application visible under DDMS so that I can debug my application using eclipse on a rooted NexusOne?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to enable debugging in your settings on your phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can see some apps but not yours, I assume you have adb working and your phone configured properly.

The next thing you'd need to check is to make sure that the "debuggable" flag is set in your application manifest.  In AndroidManifest.xml, add android:debuggable="true" to the  element.

See [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for more.  You do not need a rooted device to debug apps.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu I have to run the following commands for adb to properly recognise my devices:

```
cd <android sdk root >/tools/ (or platform-tools/ for newer SDK's)
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb devices
```

This then gives adb the right permissions to access the devices.

Then in Eclipse looking in the DDMS perspective, you select the device you want to debug (on the left) and then look in logcat (not the terminal) to see the log.

Not a solution but useful to know, Log Collector is a free app on the market which sends logs to any e-mail address and is often useful for debugging.

Comment: In the latest SDK, it's under "platform-tools"